# Proving Commandino's Theorem (concurrence of the medians of a tetrahedron)

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry

[Commandino's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Commandino%27s_theorem) states:

> The four medians of a tetrahedron are concurrent at a point S, which divides them in a 3:1 ratio. A median is any line segment that connects a vertex to the centroid of the opposite face. Point S is also the centroid of the tetrahedron.

I don't urgently need the proof to Commandino's theorem, I just want to understand it works. I have seen some proofs online, but I can't make any sense of them. One of the proofs I found came from a paper titled: [*On the Centroids of Polygons and Polyhedra*](http://forumgeom.fau.edu/FG2008volume8/FG200816.pdf). I think that it may be obvious why this proof is beyond me if you take a cursory glance at it (it's a lot of information). I came here hoping that someone will be able to provide a simpler proof, or restate the proof in a way that is easier to understand. I'm in 8th grade geometry.

---

I used Commandino's theorem to help solve the problem:

> Given a regular tetrahedron with edge length 8, find the area of the cross section that contains the intersection of the altitudes of the tetrahedron.

Comment: Using the tag `proof-explanation` means you should include a proof and point out which part of it that you don't understand.

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE! Thanks for the update. (I hope you don't mind that I made a few of edits for clarity.) I've been dealing with tetrahedra for longer than you've been alive, but I'd never known the name of the concurrent medians theorem; you've taught me something! :)  Anyway ... Can you provide links to some of the online proofs you've seen, and perhaps add a remark or two about what you didn't understand with each one? This will help answerers avoid using similar techniques only to confuse you further; and/or they might be able to explain the things that are giving you trouble.

Comment: Hi, Wesley, probably you have moved on, but I just wanted to point out that the proof in the paper is actually quite simple and short.  (You don't need to consider the part after the proof of Theorem 1.)  The clever part is really just the definitions they set up, and the proof is then just basic algebra.